# How do I make include files execute inclusively in php?

Tags: php

I've been looking at some example php code to make a members area on a website. In the examples the tutor says that you can just put `<?php include 'members_area_protection.php'; ?>` at the beginning of whatever the page is at that will execute and then the rest of the members area stuff will execute. I tried to test the theory of this by writing a php file:

```
<?php
    $name = 'Stack Overflow';
    echo $name;
?>
```

and then including it in:

```
<?php include 'namefile.php'; ?>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Members-Only Page </title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
</head>
<body>
<p>Welcome, <?=$name?>! You have entered a members-only area
   of the site. Don't you feel special?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I run the php the include file executes and echoes the name. But none of the other stuff happens. Is there a trick to getting it to carry onto the rest of the file? From my examples it doesn't look like it.

Thanks! (Sorry for the basic question I only just started using php)

Comment: What "other stuff" do you expect to happen?

Comment: Additionally to the unfinished meta-equiv line, please note that in your included file you echo a string, on top of the HTML you define in the including file. Use right-click and show-html-source in your browser to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem in this line

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Replace this with

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Or

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Otherwise code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `meta tag` isn't closed. You're missing `">`

Try:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```